# InputMap - register a keystroke that monitors key press, and no virtual repeats

Tags: java, linux, swing, key-bindings, action-interface

Apparently this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772824/how-to-set-on-key-press-key-binding?rq=1) and [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723184/java-swing-key-pressed-key-stroke-on-an-inputmap-triggers-its-action-several?rq=1) and [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917377/do-something-once-the-key-is-held-and-repeat-when-its-released-and-repressed), but either the answers are not solving the problem or use a language not understandable by me.

I have to register a keyboard action using `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, so a `KeyListener` is *not* an alternative. I have to track pressing down and releasing the key, say a cursor key. I cannot have multiple press/release firings due to some built-in key repeat. I really want to know when the key is physically pressed and depressed. E.g., **start a timer when pressed, stop the timer when released** (and do not start and stop the timer dozens of times because of the virtual key repeats).

I believe this worked correctly on OS X, but I am on Linux now (OpenJDK 7).

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As multiple people have noted, this is an oddity (or: bug) on Linux.

The work-around goes as follows. Let's say the press action class is called `ActionPress`, and the release action class is called `ActionRelease`.

- both maintain a `long lastWhen` that is updated in `actionPerformed` with `e.getWhen`. They have a public method `getLastWhen` that can be called by their counterparts.
- `ActionRelease` maintains a `javax.swing.Timer` with a few milliseconds. It's regular `actionPerformed` *restarts the timer*, nothing else.
- `ActionPress` in its `actionPerformed` calls the corresponding `ActionRelease`'s `getLastWhen`. If the result is identical to its own `lastWhen`, ignore the action and return, otherwise perform the action.
- `ActionRelease` in the additional `ActionListener` for the `Timer` performs the actual action. In its `getLastWhen` implementation, it stops the timer before return `lastWhen`.

Comment: 1. whats returns from AWTEventListener, there is repeat delay, this is part of setting in/from Native OS, 2. Swing Timer doesn't solve something

Comment: @mKorbel - the timer is only needed to skip release events that are part of the repeat. In that case, you get a release followed by a pressed with the _same time stamp_. So as long as you have a delay of at least 1 millisecond, this works, it doesn't matter what the OS's key repeat rate is actually. What is important is that the `ActionPress` can kick in first and "invalidate" the previous release event.